# Passing AngularJS variable through form input field does not work

Tags: forms, iframe, input, angularjs, field

I have an iFrame that has content on a different domain, that I also control.  I like to pass confidential data from the parent to the iFrame.  Therefore, I do not want to pass it via query string or URL.  I like to pass it via Form hidden input fields.  It works if the values of the fields are text.  However, it does not work if I use AngularJS variables as values for the fields.

Below is my code.

```
    {{session.user.user_ID}} and {{i18n.domain}} works in this HTML file and writes the correct values to the webpage.
    <form id="form_frame" action="http://other.mydomain.com/forIframe.php" method="post" target="output_frame">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{session.user.user_ID}}" name="id" />
        <input type="hidden" value="{{i18n.domain}}" name="domain" />
    </form>
    <iframe name="output_frame" width="400" height="400">
    </iframe>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
        document.getElementById("form_frame").submit(); // automatically submit the form
    </script>
```

I have this in my forIframe.php file, which is the file that writes the content for the iFrame:

```
echo 'user ID is: '.$_POST['id'];
```

However, the above writes this:

```
user ID is: {{session.user.user_ID}}
```

Why doesn't this AngularJS variable parse correctly into the value attribute of the input field?  How do I pass the values in {{session.user.user_ID}} and {{i18n.domain}} securely to my PHP file in my iFrame?

Comment: Would using ngView be acceptable for your case? Using ngView you can specify templates as external HTML pages that play nicely in an AngularJS app: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngView

Comment: @DavidRiccitelli  With ng-view pointing to other.mydomain.com/forIframe.php, I get "RangeError:  Maximum call stack size exceeded" at line 5601 in angular.js.  With ng-include, nothing appears.  With ng-include pointing to a file on www.mydomain.com, then I still have the same problem as before:  "{{session.user.user_ID}}" is passed to the PHP file, not the value of session.user.user_ID.  Thanks and I welcome any other suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Elements inside the iFrame do not inherit the scope of the parent. You best bet is to use messaging i.e. $broadcast and $on : http://plnkr.co/edit/Osa5MNKiJKzsi7wAUXgM?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I looked at the code at the link.  I cannot figure out how it passes AngularJS variables from www.domain.com to other.domain.com/forIframe.php.  Can you help by pointing out how that code does this?